# Data points' locations change when clicking into a scatter plot with the Data CUrsor

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two scatter plots on the same graph (same x, but different y values for the two series). Many data points within each series have the same x value, and so I used the jitter option of the scatter function. The code below is a simplified version of the actual code, to help with debugging:

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = [12 65 34 87 99 35 67 54 21 85];
plot1 = scatter(x, y1, 90, 'MarkerFaceColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5], 'MarkerEdgeColor', [0 0 0], 'jitter', 'on', 'jitterAmount', 2);
hold on
y2 = 1+1.1*y1;
plot2 = scatter(x, y2, 90, 's', 'MarkerFaceColor',[0.8 0.8 0.8], 'MarkerEdgeColor', [0 0 0], 'jitter', 'on', 'jitterAmount', 2);
```

In the resulting plot, when I choose the Data Cursor and click on any data point, the position of the data points changes (by quite a lot!). In the process of simplifying my code to the above minimal working example, I discovered that this is due to the jitter options; if these are removed, the problem disappears.

I actually do need to use some jitter for this plot, given the otherwise overlapping data points. But even without using the Data Cursor, it seems that the data points are plotted in incorrect locations, thus I suspect this is simply a bug with scatter's jitter options, which would make some sense given they are actually undocumented (at least in my version 2016a - [see here](https://riptutorial.com/matlab/example/30864/scatter-plot-jitter)). Can this somehow be worked around?

Comment: I don't see changes in R2018b. However, the jitter causes that I cannot klick on the markers but it shows the original/correct value (and at the correct position)

Comment: Yeah, that too. In short, it looks like the jitter options are just not usable, at least with the scatter function. Any thoughts how jitter can nonetheless be  achieved?

Comment: is preprocessing the data an option for you? You could check the distance to points and move it with random for a certain distance...

Comment: Yeah if no other easier options exist with the built-in plotting function, I'll need to do something of that sort.